# How to Convert Font in Webpage to an Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Couple of days back, While surfing web I came across some sites which uses images of text (specially for titles) to Solve the Cross Browser Font Availability issues. What is this technique called? Which technology is used to render it?

Comment: When a Title is written, it automatically gets converted to image...

Comment: Please don't do that, use google web fonts or fontsquirrel or something. The images are probably generated on the server.

Comment: @GGG What is this technique called?? Well I am just curious about it as its new to me...

Comment: It's called "ancient non-semantic cumbersome bad practice" ;)

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but I would recommend reading this tutorial and not using images for text. (http://perishablepress.com/press/2010/04/14/visual-walkthrough-font-face-css/)

Comment: I can't think of the name of it but a while back I saw this flash/JS library that would convert fonts to flash objects if the user didn't have the font installed. It was a lot of work for something meh in my opinion, though. Maybe someone will remember the name~

Comment: You'll most likely have to generate them on the server. What platform are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> Couple of days back, While surfing web I came across some sites which
>   uses images of text...

That's a very old -bad- practice.

You can now actually send the font to the user's browser (if it supports it) provided you have the right to distribute it.

In CSS, that's done like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa Regular';
    src: url('Comfortaa.eot');
    src: local('Comfortaa Regular'), 
         local('Comfortaa'), 
         url('Comfortaa.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Comfortaa.svg#font') format('svg'); 
}
```

[Check this article.](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/)

Answer (score 0):

I remember now. It's called sifr. The name for this kind of thing is typography, I guess.
http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr

Anyway, as everyone else has side this is generally speaking bad practice.

Comment: actual real custom fonts > cufon > sifr > generate image on server

Comment: @GGG I'm not implying that he should use this. His question was what technology did it use, not what is the best way to deal with cross browser font issues.

Comment: I don't think it's using SIFR though; it sounds like plain old images, probably generated on server. Otherwise it would be an SWF object, not an image.

Comment: How do they know they were automatically generated is a better question. :3 If it's just an image of a title nothing implies that it isn't that sites standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do in PHP using the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php), but as an end user you wouldn't be able to tell.